# Promise pending on async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to get data from an API request but I don't know why await does not wait to get data to return value. Anyone can help me?

```js
async function getChampionMasteryData(championId, summonerName) {  
    try {
        var summonerId = process.env.SUMMONER_ID;
        
        let championMasteryData = await axios(`https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/champion-mastery/v4/champion-masteries/by-summoner/${summonerId}/by-champion/${championId}?api_key=${process.env.API_KEY}`, {responseType: 'json'});

        return championMasteryData.data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Output:

```js
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? What's the value of `championMasteryData`?

Comment: the return is a promise pending.

Comment: How did you log the returned value?

Comment: Because async functions _always_ return a promise, and so whatever function is calling `getChampionMasteryData` should be async too. In fact I would just return the data from the function without it being async, and let the function that's calling it deal with the `try/catch`.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite likely that you are not awaiting for the `getChampionMasteryData` function. You should call it like `await getChampionMasteryData(championId, summonerName)` instead of calling it directly.

If you want to call it from a non-async function, you can use `then` to wait until it resolves like below,

```
getChampionMasteryData(championId, summonerName).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I've done this, but still returning me a promise pending: " const championMasteryData = lolapi.getChampionMasteryData(championId, 'manufm').then( res => console.log(res.data) );

console.log(championMasteryData);"

Comment: Can you share the code that you're calling this function from?

Comment: https://github.com/gitatmanu/Champion-Mastery-Display-for-OBS

Comment: The problem is in `http.createServer(function (req, res)`, it needs to be like `http.createServer(async function (req, res) { ...` and after doing this, you'll be able to await before ending the response. You also have to change the `lolapi.getChampionMasteryData ...).then` part to `await lolapi.getChampionMasteryData()`.

To clarify why you can't do it the other way, your callback function is not `async`, and inside your callback function you're trying to `await`.  It either has to be `async` or you should put res.end and res.writeHead inside the `then` callback.

Comment: Lol, you're welcome. Edited the comment so you can have a better idea of how it works in general.

Comment: I appreciate your help to teach me, thank you and have a good day!